# Конвертер программы с языка Си

Tags: c, конвертер

Вообщем дали курсовую писать.  И надо написать конвертер программы с языка Си на язык Паскаль. В голове стразу же представилось, какая форма и прочее... а вот представления, что и как делать вообще нет.

Подскажите, с чего начать, что прочитать или как делать? Не прошу ведь готовую программу.

Заранее спасибо!

Написать надо на Си++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google + Парсер, лексемы, Синтаксический анализ, Лексический анализ

Ну и почитать статьи где разрабатывается свой ЯП, а именно реализация синтаксиса.

Comment: разрабатывается свой ЯП?
книжки не посоветуете по этому?
спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Например [тут][1] есть очень много интересного


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/tag/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/119850/) есть статья по созданию языка программирования. Первые 2 главы показывают, как построить синтаксическое дерево программы. Думаю, по аналогии, сможешь переделать на C. Когда построишь дерево, уже будет достаточно просто сгенерировать по нему код на другом языке.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу... Буду что нибуть да пробывать

Answer (score 0):

Вообще эта задача далеко не из простых. Как вариант можно посмотреть на проект LLVM. Он позволяет конвертировать из C в C++: [Can I use LLVM to convert C++ code to C code?](http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#translatecxx). Код открытый, так что его можно переиспользовать.

Comment: >Он позволяет конвертировать из C в C++

 Может, наоборот, из C++ в C?